# How to read character/string before and after symbol

Tags: php

i want to make some variable which the resource is a range variabel, can someone help me to read the string '-' and ';'

```
 $temp='25-30;18-20';
        $tempmin1=//before '-'result is 25
        $tempmax1=//after '-' result is 30 
        $tempmin2=//before '-'result is 18
        $tempmax2=//after '-' result is 20
```

Comment: Take a look at `preg_split()`

Comment: Better to use `explode` instead of `preg_split` what you say @Rizier123

Comment: @Uchiha OP has multiple delimiters, so `preg_split`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
$temp='25-30;18-20';
$temparr = preg_split("/\-|\;/", $temp);
```

Now,

$temparr[0] would be  $tempmin1 before '-'result is 25

$temparr[0] would be  $tempmax1 after '-' result is 30

$temparr[0] would be  $tempmin2 before '-'result is 18

$temparr[0] would be  $tempmax2 after '-' result is 20